# byte[] keeps accumulating data while streaming and do not push just the current data

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, streaming, spring-4

I am using java 8, Spring 4.3.x and Tomcat 7.

**Below is my code for Streaming huge data from database in the form of chunks.**

```
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> streamRecords(HttpServletRequest request, 
            HttpServletResponse response,....) 
    throws Exception {      
    int recordSize = 5000;
    int pageSize = 1000;
    StreamingResponseBody responseBody = outputStream -> {
        byte[] bytes = null;
        for (int skip = 0 ; skip <= recordSize ; skip += pageSize) {
            logger.error("SKIP: " + skip);
            try {
                JsonObject records = new JsonObject();
                .
                .//somewhere down the call is below code
                .//dbCursor = dbCollection.find().skip(skip).limit(pageSize);
                .
                .
                .
                bytes = records.toString().getBytes();
                outputStream.write(bytes);
                outputStream.flush();
                logger.error("BYTE LENGTH: " + bytes.length);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Exception occured while streaming records: " + e.getMessage() + "\n", e);
                    outputStream.close();
            }
        }
        outputStream.close();
    };
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=sample.csv")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .body(responseBody);
}
```

> NOTE: The outputstream used is [CoyoteOutputStream.java](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/CoyoteOutputStream.java.html)

**The Actual output is as below,**

```
2019-05-14/15:48:30.850/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 0
2019-05-14/15:48:49.596/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 282462
2019-05-14/15:48:49.606/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 1000
2019-05-14/15:49:07.777/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 565633
2019-05-14/15:49:07.793/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 2000
2019-05-14/15:49:26.426/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 849231
2019-05-14/15:49:26.433/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 3000
2019-05-14/15:49:45.595/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 1132467
2019-05-14/15:49:45.625/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 4000
2019-05-14/15:50:03.962/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 1416003
2019-05-14/15:50:03.996/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 5000
2019-05-14/15:50:24.028/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 1699420
```

**Expected output somewhat as below.**

```
2019-05-14/15:48:30.850/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 0
2019-05-14/15:48:49.596/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 282462
2019-05-14/15:48:49.606/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 1000
2019-05-14/15:49:07.777/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 292462
2019-05-14/15:49:07.793/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 2000
2019-05-14/15:49:26.426/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 282462
2019-05-14/15:49:26.433/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 3000
2019-05-14/15:49:45.595/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 292462
2019-05-14/15:49:45.625/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 4000
2019-05-14/15:50:03.962/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 282462
2019-05-14/15:50:03.996/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - SKIP: 5000
2019-05-14/15:50:24.028/IST[MvcAsync1] ERROR - BYTE LENGTH: 292462
```

The bytes must be fresh copy of present chunk but somehow it taking previous chunks as well while I am writing to outputStream. as per recordSize, I am expecting 5000 records, but I am getting 21000 records.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: How do you read `records`? Seems like you don't skip the previously read ones

Comment: @Lino: Thanks for reply,I do skip previously read one. I have written shorter code for quick understanding.

Comment: The part of the code that could hold the error seems left out. Looks to me that the object that fills 'records' isn't emptied before the next iteration.

Comment: @WesleyDeKeirsmaeker: Thanks for reply, if you see `JsonObject records = new JsonObject();`, I am always creating new instance in for loop.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? @AnkurSoni

Comment: Did you solve your problem? @AnkurSoni

Comment: Yes. The code is absolutely correct. The issue was with my other peice of code.

Comment: Can request you to post an answer here, If possible. Thanks for replying and for your precious time and reply. @AnkurSoni